# How to gmock member function with a templated return type?

Tags: c++, templates, googlemock

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using testing::_;
using testing::AllOf;
using testing::Args;

struct Base {
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Base constructed" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    T* getVar() {
        return new T; // Ignore memory leak, this is for test case
    }
};

struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo& f) : f(f) {}

    virtual void testFoo() {
        f.getVar<Base>();
    }

    Foo f;
};

struct FooMock : public Foo {
    // How to mock getVar()?
};


struct TestBar : public Bar, public ::testing::Test {
    TestBar() : Bar(f) {}

    FooMock f;
};

TEST_F(TestBar, TestCase)
{
    testFoo();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PzTdG3a14

How can I mock `getVar()`? The return type is templated.
I cannot get `MOCK_METHOD` to work with templated types and have no idea how to fit the function into that macro. I want to completely avoid rewriting `getVar()` for the sake of mocking.

**EDIT**: Ignoring the missing `virtual` if I use [Hi-perf dependency injection](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#MockingNonVirtualMethods) how can you `MOCK_METHOD` the templated return type member function?

Comment: You mostly mock interface, template functions cannot be `virtual`...

Comment: What if I use [hi-perf dependency injection](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#MockingNonVirtualMethods)? That lets you mock non-virtual functions. How can I then `MOCK_METHOD`?

Comment: Then `Bar` need to be template.

Comment: Seems to break at line 30: https://godbolt.org/z/Ydb9xsz7T

Comment: Offtopic: please do not inherit class under test as a testsuite! So do not do that: `struct TestBar : public Bar`

Comment: Missing `template` for dependent name [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8E3KTrsaP)

Comment: "Missing template for dependent name"
What is that? Why can you put `template` into a function call like that? I don't understand what's happening on that line.

Comment: "Offtopic: please do not inherit class under test as a testsuite!"
@MarekR I needed to access protected members of Bar which isn't showing in my example.

Comment: "I needed to access protected members of Bar" - then you are not testing it correctly; Test observable behavior, not implementation details. So, e.g. if you want to test that your `class Bar` is suitable to be inherited from, in your tests create `class TestBar: public Bar`, provide the public interfaces that make correct use of protected members, and then use the instance of `TestBar tb;` in your test fixture `class BarFixture: public testing::Test`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9TMe6vWTd

Comment: See [where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for the missing `template`.

Comment: Thanks @MarekR You should put that as the answer imo. I'll put some comments on it for questions I have about it.